# form input text showing up as either "undefined" or "[object HTMLInputElement]"

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with the id's name, title, and description for respective input boxes.
However when I try to display those values in HTML I either receive "[object HTMLInputElement]" or "undefined".

**I get "undefined"** for the below block of code where I have declared the variables name, title and description **globally** outside the functions to retrieve input values.

```
var name;
var title;
var description;      
document.getElementById("name").onchange = function(){
      name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      };
document.getElementById("title").onchange = function(){
          title = document.getElementById("title").value;
      };
document.getElementById("description").onchange = functio){
          description = document.getElementById("description").value;
      };

var myhtml = '<p>' + name + '</p><p>' + title + '</p><p>' + description + '</p><p>';
```

However, I get **[object HTMLInputElement]** if I instead declare the variables inside the functions (instead of "globally"?), like so:

```
document.getElementById("name").onchange = function(){
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      };
```

myHTML is the variable which is printed in the DOM.

What's going on here? I've tried passing name, title, and description into the functions if I have them globally declared. But that did not solve the problem (I still got "[object HTMLInputElement]").

Comment: `undefined`, because the variables are not defined at run-time (you're setting the values inside event listeners, which have obviously not been triggered when `myhtml` was declared). `[object HTMLInputElement]`, because elements with ID attributes can be accessed as `window["id_of_element"]`, provided that there's no global variable called `id_of_element`.

Comment: How is myhtml "printed" in the DOM? You have defined onchange events, so the values will not be shown except with the handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys. Right now I'm tinkering with function decompositions, scope, and run-times as @RobW 's comment has hinted to me. That chunk of code above was part of a doubly nested "click" function, which were inside two dom/window init functions. So things may have gotten messy.

Comment: Also, I am now getting [Object object] for one of the values after moving the block around.

Comment: Downvoter should explain downvote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "undefined" values are due to the "onchange" events not having fired until the inputs have changed. This jsfiddle illustrates my point: http://jsfiddle.net/gR8td/ . Note that after typing values for the input elements, the new values of global variables are shown. I added the following function to output the values:

```
function showInputs() {
    var myhtml = '<p>' + name + '</p><p>' + title + '</p><p>' + description + '</p>';
    var elem=document.getElementById('output');
    elem.innerHTML = myhtml;
}
```

Comment: Yep, as you hinted it was due to the "onchange" events firing too early; in my case this was due to their function which assigned values to the name, title, and description variables being inside a function which may have initiated before the DOM and the form even loaded. I moved the block of code to a traditional $(document).ready() function to make sure the form was loaded first.

Thanks for the great jsFiddle.